# Nginx configuration with engine_ssl pkcs11 for set TLS connections

Tags: nginx, pkcs#11

Please help me with nginx configuration on Windows for use TLS connections based on PKCS#11 engine.

I have driver pkcs11 (C:\nCipher\nfast\toolkits\pkcs11\cknfast-64.dll) from provider.

My nginx.conf file looks like:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

#nShield PKCS#11
ssl_engine pkcs11;


http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate      C:/nginx-1.16.1/ssl/test_selfcert;
        ssl_certificate_key  "engine:pkcs11:pkcs11:token=ocs2;object=test_key";

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to check this config and get error:

```
>nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] ENGINE_by_id("pkcs11") failed (SSL: error:25078067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library:filename(Z:\nginx\nginx-stab
le\objs.msvc8\lib\openssl-1.1.1c\openssl\lib\engines-1_1\pkcs11.dll) error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library error:260B60
84:engine routines:dynamic_load:dso not found error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:id=pkcs11)
nginx: configuration file C:\nginx-1.16.1/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

I think there is an error in my openssl configuration because I did not define the pkcs11 driver there.
At the end of the default configuration C:\nCipher\nfast\lib\ssleay\openssl.cnf I added a block like:

```
...
openssl_conf            = openssl_def
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
chil = chil_section

[chil_section]
SO_PATH=c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nCipher\\nfast\\toolkits\\hwcrhk\\nfhwcrhk.dll

#added
[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section
[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSLx64\\bin\\pkcs11openssl64x.dll"
MODULE_PATH = "C:\\nCipher\\nfast\\toolkits\\pkcs11\\cknfast-64.dll"
init = 0
...
```

But file pkcs11openssl64x.dll is NOT exist on my computer! In 'dynamic_path' param I tried to download and use  files libpkcs11-helper-1.dll, onepin-opensc-pkcs11.dll, opensc_pkcs11.ddl , but all of them not working. When I tried to use this configuration without 'dynamic_path' param, i get error:

```
> openssl engine -t -c pkcs11
13112:error:25078067:DSO support routines:WIN32_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_win32.c:179:filename(C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\lib\engines\pkcs11.
dll)
13112:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:233:
13112:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:467:
13112:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:411:id=pkcs11
```

or with use config path:

```
> openssl engine -t -c pkcs11  -config "C:\nCipher\nfast\lib\ssleay\openssl.cnf"
13572:error:25078067:DSO support routines:WIN32_LOAD:could not load the shared 
library:./crypto/dso/dso_win32.c:179:filename(C:\nCipher\nfast\bin\pkcs11.dll)
13572:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:./crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:233:
13572:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:./crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:467:
13572:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:./crypto/engine/eng_list.c:391:id=pkcs11
13572:error:25078067:DSO support routines:WIN32_LOAD:could not load the shared library:./crypto/dso/dso_win32.c:179:filename(C:\nCipher\nfast\bin\-config.dll)
13572:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:./crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:233:
13572:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:./crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:467:
13572:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:./crypto/engine/eng_list.c:391:id=-config
13572:error:25078067:DSO support routines:WIN32_LOAD:could not load the shared library:./crypto/dso/dso_win32.c:179:filename(C:\nCipher\nfast\lib\ssleay\\openss
l.cnf)
13572:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:./crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:233:
13572:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:./crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:467:
13572:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:./crypto/engine/eng_list.c:391:id=C:\nCipher\nfast\lib\ssleay\openssl.cnf
```

But I'm expecting the next:

```
> openssl engine -t -c pkcs11
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
[RSA, rsaEncryption, id-ecPublicKey]
[ available ]
```

Also no pkcs#11 driver are detected when outputting:

```
>openssl engine -t -c
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
     [ unavailable ]
(chil) CHIL hardware engine support
 [RSA, DH, RAND]
     [ available ]
```

Please help me to set the correct configuration for NGINX to work with TLS connection setup.

Comment: Somebody, please, prompt articles where it is told how to work with the driver PKCS#11 for NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the P11 engine library; see this answer for how you might get it for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287898/7369488

On Linux platforms that component is normally available through the distribution repository, which means a considerably easier setup of nginx.

For help with nShield devices meanwhile visit: https://nshieldsupport.entrust.com/

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have an nCipher HSM?  Which version of security world software are you running?  The PKCS#11 dlls should have been on the install ISO.  Have you already created a Security World?

Your configuration is trying to use both the CHIL engine and PKCS#11.  These are two different APIs for talking to Hardserver, pick one but not both.